# Cropping picture, getting Rectangle from X,Y?

Tags: c#, coordinates, points

I'm trying to crop a picture in C# from integer x, y coordinates.. 
I just can't figure out how to get it?

```
public void doCroppedImage(int pointX, int pointY)
{
    Rectangle cropRect = //???
}
```

Comment: that appears to be because you haven't written any code yet...

Comment: What is `pointX`, `pointY`? Packed coordinates with x in loword and y in hiword? Or just x and y of the same point, with (0,0) always being the other point?

Comment: One point does not make a rectangle. Basic geometry. See [Rectangle structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this code. It returns the cropped image.

```
public static Bitmap CropImage(Image source, int x,int y,int width,int height)
{
    Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(crop.Width, crop.Height);
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gr.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), crop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

But one comment, to crop an image you have to know not only the x and y coordinates of cropping point but also the width and height of the cropped image.